# Does the order of adjectives, "fresh" and "fried", affect meaning?

Tags: meaning, word-order, compound-adjectives, adjective-position

> 1. Fresh fried fish
> 2. Fried fresh fish
> 3. Fish fried fresh
> 4. Fish fresh fried
> 5. Fried fish fresh

What's the difference between the ways of writing the same idea above?
What are the differences in meaning?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Fresh fried fish

The fish is fresh and fried - the freshness of the fish is important

> 2. Fried fresh fish

As above - the fish is fresh and fried - that is it fried is important

> 3. Fish fried fresh

This is clunky - the fish is fried soon after having been caught

> 4. Fish fresh fried

Incorrect, *Fish freshly fried* is correct - and the fish has been fried recently

> 5. Fried fish fresh

Incorrect, cannot be salvaged

Lastly you can have *Freshly fried fish* e.g. recently fried

Comment: *Fish fried fresh* means the fish was fresh when it was fried. Perfectly grammatical (although maybe not really useful for the case of fish).

Comment: Ok - amended that one

Comment: I believe "Freshly fried fish" would imply that the frying was fresh (i.e. recent). It would not necessarily imply that the fish was fresh. Adjective "fresh" modifies the noun, but adverb "freshly" modifies the verb.

Comment: @DJClayworth - updated

Comment: "Fried fish fresh" can be salvaged if you'll allow: "Do I smell fresh?" "Sure ... fried fish fresh ..."

Comment: "Do you want fish, Carlton?" "Sure, fried fish fresh prince"